# Vim: Add closing buckles, brackets, quotation marks etc. automatically?

Tags: vim

This is something what I miss from other editors. I'm looking for a plugin/config which adds closing mark for some characters automatically.

For example, when I type `(`, it add `)` and prompt will be between it. Similarly with `{`, `"` etc. This would be very helpful for me. I know I can do it using Vim command, but my goal is do it automatically.

Comment: There are many plugins (see http://vim.wikia.com/index.php?title=Automatically_append_closing_characters) and many questions SO on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin named auto-pairs.vim available in github. See here : https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs

It can automatically insert closing brackets and quotes and puts prompt in between both.

It is smart and doesn't insert matching brackets for escaped brackets. It works even if you nest different brackets.

Comment: Works awesome, just like I want. Thank you! :)